# Bootstrap modals not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get modals from bootstrap to work but for some reason it is showing up like this: 
[image: Image Example]

This is the default code I used from the bootstrap documentation:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to be a CSS issue. Your HTML works out for me. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/10201/) Could you also post your CSS?

Comment: @Ramis Wachtler i assume the bootstrap.css http://puu.sh/fHuMr/e43c6de42e.css

Comment: need to update your bootstrap.css or may be some of your custom css overwrite bootstrap modal css. check modal-dialog class of css.

Comment: @Timo I meant that some of your custom CSS is overriding the standard Bootstrap CSS. You could build up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), with your code and your custom CSS, so we can take a closer look why your modal is being displayed like this.

Comment: I've found it i had 2 different CDN lines in my header one outdated and on uptodate just a silly mistake of me -,- thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Fixed just putting this here to close it ;D

i used the wrong CDN

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the modal with javascript? All you need is JQuery, the bootstrap CSS file, and the bootstrap JS file.

Then add this code in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of your page!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```